# Using tryCatch within plyr

Tags: r, plyr

I'm running this function:

```
require(XML)
require(plyr)


getKeyStats_xpath <- function(symbol) {
  yahoo.URL <- "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="
  html_text <- htmlParse(paste(yahoo.URL, symbol, sep = ""), encoding="UTF-8")

  #search for <td> nodes anywhere that have class 'yfnc_tablehead1'
  nodes <- getNodeSet(html_text, "/*//td[@class='yfnc_tablehead1']")

  if(length(nodes) > 0 ) {
    measures <- sapply(nodes, xmlValue)

    #Clean up the column name
    measures <- gsub(" *[0-9]*:", "", gsub(" \\(.*?\\)[0-9]*:","", measures))   

    #Remove dups
    dups <- which(duplicated(measures))
    #print(dups) 
    for(i in 1:length(dups)) 
      measures[dups[i]] = paste(measures[dups[i]], i, sep=" ")

    #use siblings function to get value
    values <- sapply(nodes, function(x)  xmlValue(getSibling(x)))

    df <- data.frame(t(values))
    colnames(df) <- measures
    return(df)
  } else {
    break
  }
}
```

As long as the page exists, it works fine.  However, if one of my tickers does NOT have any data on that URL, it throws an error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[3L]], ...) : no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
```

I added a trace too, and things break down on ticker number 3.

```
tickers <- c("QLTI",
"RARE",
"RCPT",
"RDUS",
"REGN",
"RGEN",
"RGLS")

tryCatch({
stats <- ldply(tickers, getKeyStats_xpath)
}, finally={})
```

I'd like to call the function like this:

```
stats <- ldply(tickers, getKeyStats_xpath)
rownames(stats) <- tickers
write.csv(t(stats), "FinancialStats_updated.csv",row.names=TRUE)
```

Basically, if a ticker has no data, I want to skip it.

Can someone please help me get this working?

Comment: Write a wrapper for `getKeyStats_xpath` that encloses it in `tryCatch`. you could do this within `ldply` with an anonymous function, for example `ldply(tickers, function (t) tryCatch(getKeyStats_xpath(t), finally={}))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write trycatch in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment. The issue here is you've enclosed the entire command `stats <- ldply(tickers, getKeyStats_xpath)` within a `tryCatch`. This means R will try to get key stats from every ticker.

Instead, what you want is to try each ticker.

To do this, write a wrapper for `getKeyStats_xpath` that encloses it in `tryCatch`. you could do this within `ldply` with an anonymous function, for example `ldply(tickers, function (t) tryCatch(getKeyStats_xpath(t), finally={}))`. Note that finally executes regardless of exit condition, so finally={} executes nothing. (See [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html#condition-handling) or [How to write try catch in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r) from r-faq for more).

On an error, `tryCatch` calls the function provided in the argument `error`. So as is, this code still won't help as the error is unhandled (thanks to rawr for pointing this out earlier).  It is also easier to inspect the output if you use `llply` instead, then

So a complete answer using this approach, and with informative error handling, is below.

```
stats <- llply(tickers, 
    function(t) tryCatch(getKeyStats_xpath(t), 
        error=function(x) {
            cat("error occurred for:\n", t, "\n...skipping this ticker\n")
        }
    )
)
names(stats) <- tickers
lapply(stats, length)
#<snip>
#$RCPT
#[1] 0
# </snip>
```

As of now, this works for me, returning data for all tickers except the one listed in the code block above.

Comment: Sorry, but I guess I'm missing something here.  I tried this:
stats <- ldply(tickers,  function(t) tryCatch(getKeyStats_xpath(t), error=function(x) {cat("error occurred\n")}))

I tried this too:
stats <- ldply(tickers,  function(t) tryCatch(getKeyStats_xpath(t)))

Both attempts ended the same way:
Error in getKeyStats_xpath(t) : 
  no loop for break/next, jumping to top level

Comment: I tried this:
ldply(tickers, function (t) tryCatch(getKeyStats_xpath(t), finally={}))

I keep getting this error:
Error: could not find function "ldply"

The concept definitely makes sense to me, and I've used TryCatch many times in C# & SQL, but I can't seem to get this working in R.



I gool

Comment: I guess that's the problem.  Weird thing is, I just installed it, and got confirmation that it installed fine.  But I invoke it and get an error.

require(plyr)
Loading required package: plyr
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘plyr’

Comment: Sorry for dragging this on so long everyone.  It seems like there was a problem with 'plyr' yesterday, but it's working today.  I just tried this:


stats <- ldply(tickers,  function(t) tryCatch(getKeyStats_xpath(t), error=function(x) {cat("error occurred\n")}))

I get 'error occurred'.  I can see why, but I don't know how to handle this exception.  Basically, if the ticker doesn't have any 'key statistics', I want to skip it and continue reading other tickers in the array.  There must be an easy way to do this, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98150/discussion-between-ryguy72-and-jaimedash).